# Organizing Chef resources and extending cookbooks: Apache2 package + Compiled PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, chef

I'm trying to understand how to organize my Chef kitchen and extend the functionality of Opscode community cookbooks. **Disclaimer:** n00b.

*PLANNED STACK*

- Ubuntu 12.04.2
- Apache2 (package)
- PHP 5.4.13 (compiled)
- MySQL Server
- MySQL Client

**APACHE COOKBOOK + COMPILED PHP**

The Apache cookbook only offers a recipe for installing php as a package. The official Ubuntu 12.04 package installs PHP 5.3 and there is no good unofficial 5.4+ package. The application requires PHP 5.4+. Therefore, PHP must be compiled from source with the `"--with-apxs2"` flag.

**APXS**

To compile PHP to work with Apache2 requires apxs2 (or apxs), which doesn't appear to be installed by the `apache::default` recipe (even though `apache2 -l` shows `mod_so.c` and [the apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apxs.html) seem to indicate that this indicates installation.)

1. I did notice that line 142-143 of [the default apache.conf.erb template](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/templates/default/apache2.conf.erb) has a commented out `LoadModule` line with something about "keeping apxs happy", but I didn't understand its purpose. Is there something simple I'm missing in the Apache2 docs that shows how to install or enable apxs?
2. The Apache cookbook doesn't offer a method for installing the `dev` package. So where should this installation occur? My 'sample_lamp_app' recipe? In a cookbook like 'my_apache2' that "extends" the community cookbook? The 'php::source' recipe, with a `not_if` conditional that test for apxs?

**NOTE**

Please don't answer with things like "upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10" or "use this unofficial Apache2 cookbook instead". First, the project spec requires 12.04. Second I'm more interested in learning the proper methods for organizing and interacting within cookbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question to one of the guys from Opscode at a conference a couple of weeks ago..

We currently use an old version of chef (10.14.4) because it allows you to store cookbooks in multiple locations and chef will merge them all together. When you do this, it warns of deprecated behavior but the Opscode guy didn't seem to have an answer for the correct way to do it.

**Directory structure**

We override only the parts we want to change, and the metadata file. In this case, we've copied the *default.rb* file, made changes and saved it in our *cookbooks-overrides* directory. Note that we also copied over *metadata.rb*, in which we've bumped the version number. I usually prepend a 9, so that my version is always the highest, making the version something like *92.2.13* instead of *2.2.13*. In this way, I use the 9 as a type of namespace.

```
`-- chef
    |-- cookbooks
    |   `-- apache2
    |       |-- attributes
    |       |   `-- ...
    |       |-- CHANGELOG.md
    |       |-- CONTRIBUTING.md
    |       |-- definitions
    |       |   `-- ...
    |       |-- files
    |       |   `-- ...
    |       |-- Gemfile
    |       |-- LICENSE
    |       |-- metadata.json
    |       |-- metadata.rb
    |       |-- README.md
    |       |-- recipes
    |       |   `-- ...
    |       `-- templates
    |           `-- ...
    `-- cookbooks-overrides
        `-- apache2
            |-- metadata.rb
            `-- recipes
                `-- default.rb
```

**knife.rb**

We tell Chef where to look for the cookbooks

```
...
cookbook_path [
    "#{ENV['HOME']}/dev/deployment/chef/cookbooks",
    "#{ENV['HOME']}/dev/deployment/chef/cookbooks-overrides"
]
```

Now when you push the cookbook to your chef server with *knife cookbook upload* , you'll get a warning because the cookbook exists in more than one place, but it will still happily merge them together and you'll end up with one cookbook which does what you want.

This is, I'm sure, not "the way" to do it, but it's certainly one way which as been successful for us so far. It just takes a bit of diligence to make sure your overrides still work when you update the underlying cookbook (in this case, apache2).

**Other references**

[This post](http://dougireton.com/blog/2013/02/16/chef-cookbook-anti-patterns/) talks about creating a 'wrapper cookbook' to do what you want.

[This post](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2011/06/12/manage-your-third-party-chef-cookbooks-with-knife-github-cookbooks/) talks about a tool to manage third party cookbooks.